# How to put logic into SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

First at all i am sorry for asking silly question like this. 
I am new into sql. Leaned basic things from internet but cant figure this out.

Lets think i have a table named post where i store peoples post. Table structure is like this..

```
Post_id  | poster_id | text
1        | 12        | "hello this is a post"
2        | 15        | "Another post"
3        | 77        | "More counting"
```

There is a table named "Friends" Where i store whos friend is who. Table structure is like this..

```
user_one  |  user_two
1         |  88
84        |  33
1         |  66
```

Now i can use SQL like this to get post from post

```
SELECT * FROM POST INNER JOIN frnends ON user_one = poster_id WHERE 1
```

But this will get a table by joining two table together, Cant i do some logic like this?

> SELECT post FROM post WHERE poster_id = (SELECT user_two,user_one FROM friends WHERE user_one = MY_id OR user_two = MY_id

perhaps MY_id is a variable WHERE MY_id = 1

Now to do this kind of logic?

Any help will be so great.

Comment: You should specify what you want to accomplish. Do you want to see all your posts, and all your friends' posts, or just your friends' posts? Also, in Friends, if I am your friend, are you automatically my friend? Or do I always choose my friends?

Comment: We both are friend. I want to get my friends post aswell mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I lack the reputation to comment.  Gamal's solution should be refined to prevent the return of My_id's posts;

```
SELECT *
FROM post p
INNER JOIN friends AS f on p.poster_id IN (f.user_one, f.user_two)
WHERE My_id IN (f.user_one, f.user_two)
AND p.poster<>My_id;
```

Or if you do want those posts as well;

```
SELECT *
FROM post p
INNER JOIN friends AS f on p.poster_id IN (f.user_one, f.user_two)
WHERE My_id IN (f.user_one, f.user_two)
AND p.poster<>My_id
UNION
SELECT *, My_id AS user_one, NULL AS user_two
FROM post p
WHERE p.poster=My_id;
```

The problem is that Gamals suggestion will return each post by My_id once for every relation that My_id is part of.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   SELECT * 
    FROM [sample].[dbo].[posts] a inner join [sample].[dbo].[friends1] b on  a.posterId=b.user_one or a.posterId=b.user_two where a.PosterId=12
```

Comment: I think it is wrong dialect of SQL. It doesn't work with MySQL and is not a standard.